# I need gitignore to ignore everything except one folder and everything that is in it

Tags: wordpress, git, gitignore

I need everything to be ignored except the /wp-content/themes/spk7sy folder itself and everything that is in it.

I wrote this:

```
/*
!/wp-content/themes/spk7sy/
```

But for some reason all the files are not ignored.

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a little more complex

- So first you ignore all with `*`
- But not wp-content so `!wp-content/`
- Then you want to ignore all in wp-content so `wp-content/*`
- etc..

```
*
!wp-content/
wp-content/*
!wp-content/themes/
wp-content/themes/*
!wp-content/themes/spk7sy
!wp-content/themes/spk7sy/*
```

Comment: For some reason it doesn't work :(

Comment: As if git does not count with gitignore at all

Comment: you need a first file commited into the directory

Comment: I don't understand, can you explain?

Comment: Consider using `/*` for the top entry to avoid having to un-ignore anything in a subdirectory of the un-ignored path.

Comment: @torek this will not work all files inside `wp-content/` will be seen whereas only themes dir should be not ignored

Comment: `/**` should work

Comment: @Ôrel: The `/*` will ignore all files and directories at the top level. The `!wp-content/` will cause `wp-content/` itself to be scanned despite this. Then the `wp-content/*` will cause all files and directories at that level to be ignored, except that the `!wp-content/themes/` entry will cause the `themes` sub-directory to be scanned. Then the `wp-content/themes/*` will cause all files and directories at *this* level to be ignored, except that the one `spk7sy` entry (file or directory) will not be ignored: if it is a directory, it will be scanned. Then `!wp-content/themes/spk7sy/*` applies.

Comment: The key to my comment is this: `*` means everything at *all levels*, but `/*` and `dir/*` means *everything at the top level* and *everything in `dir/`* respectively. That's because an entry with a leading or embedded slash applies only to names *at that level*, while an entry with no slash or only a trailing slash applies to names at *that level or any sub-level*.